# elasticsearch:painless script params error

Tags: elasticsearch

the query body:

```
{
    "query": {
    "script": {
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "inline": "doc['TIME'].date.getHourOfDay() > 8 && doc['TIME'].date.getHourOfDay() <= 9",
            "params": {
                "startHour": 8,
                "endHour": 9
            }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 1
}
```

I can get the query result from es5.0.
but when I use the params to replace the number(8 and 9),such as:

```
"inline": "doc['TIME'].date.getHourOfDay() > startHour && 
    doc['TIME'].date.getHourOfDay() <= endHour",
    "params": {
      "startHour": 8,
      "endHour": 9
    }
```

...

ES return a error as below:

```
"caused_by": {
"type": "script_exception",
"reason": "compile error",
"caused_by": {
             "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
             "reason": "Variable [startHour] is not defined."
          },
```

...

what's the problem?